# "No such column" error for model type join scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, join, scope, associations

I have two models (Person and Customer) that share a table in the DB using Rails' "type" parameter to separate them:

```
# Person.rb
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end

# Customer.rb
class Customer < Person
  has_many :orders
end
```

And also, an orders table:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

I'm running a test to retreive customers who have ordered within the last 90 days:

```
# Inside of Customer.rb
  def self.ordered_in_last_90_days
    scoped.joins(:orders).where('orders.created_at > ?', 90.days.ago)
  end
```

But I'm receiving the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: orders.customer_id: SELECT "people".* FROM "people" INNER JOIN "orders" ON "orders"."customer_id" = "people"."id" WHERE "people"."type" IN ('Customer') AND (orders.created_at > '2013-06-18 16:47:44.726372')
```

The join is looking for "orders.customer_id" when it should be looking for "orders.person_id". How can I make this correction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify foreign_key:

```
 class Customer < Person
   has_many :orders, foreign_key: person_id
 end
```

Comment: Ahh I see. I had tried that by adding the `foreign_key` attribute to the `Order` model. Apparently I need to add it to the customer instead. Thanks for the quick help!